# Elixir regex replacing square brakets and comma

Tags: regex, elixir

As mentioned above, the goal is to remove square brackets and commas.
My current solution is the following:

Given:

```
"[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]"
|> String.replace("[", "")
|> String.replace(",", "")
|> String.replace("]", "")
|> String.split(" ")
|> Enum.map(fn x -> String.to_float(x) end)
```

Output:

```
[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]
```

I know this can be compacted much more, but I've been looking at examples all day and all failed to do the job above.

Comment: `String.replace(~r'[][,]+', "")`

Comment: Just in case you are already using some sort of JSON library (e.g. Poison) for other purposes, you could use Poison.decode!("[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a string, you can pass a regex to `String.replace`. In Elixir you can build a regex with `~r` [sigil](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#regular-expressions).

```
"[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]"
|> String.replace(~r'[\[\],]', "")
|> String.split()
|> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While @fhdhsni has given you a great answer if your concern is readability I'd suggest abstracting the whole thing to a separate function like so:

```
defmodule T do 
    def parsefloats(stringtobeparsed) do
        stringtobeparsed
        |> String.replace("[", "")
        |> String.replace(",", "")
        |> String.replace("]", "")
        |> String.split(" ")
        |> Enum.map(fn x -> String.to_float(x) end)
    end
end
```

Then you call it like so:

```
[x,y] = T.parsefloats("[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]")
# [40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]
iex(3)> x
# 40.45694301152436
iex(4)> y
# -3.6907402812214514
```

Not any better in terms of more compact code but more readable I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using `String.slice`:

```
"[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]" 
|> String.slice(1..-2) 
|> String.split(~r/,\s+/) 
|> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the string replace solutions, you can take a look at [Code.eval_string](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3) as well.

This way the string will get parsed and you'll get back the list you're looking for;

```
{list, _} = Code.eval_string "[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]"
# {[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514], []}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment on your question about using a JSON parser is best, followed by fhdhsni's simple answer. But here's a method that extracts the numbers, rather than replacing the brackets:

```
str = "[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]"
regex = ~r/([\d\.-]+), ([\d\.+-]+)/
Regex.run(regex, str, capture: :all_but_first) |> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)
```

Output:

```
[40.45694301152436, -3.6907402812214514]
```